# got puzzled about promise in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

1 the value can not change in promise
for example

```js
var t = function(s) {
  var wait = function(dtd) {　　　　
    var dtd = $.Deferred();
    //new a Deferred object in function
    　　　　
    var tasks = function() {　　　　　　
      alert("complete!");
      s = s + "hhh";　　　　　　
      dtd.resolve(s); // change the state of deferred object　　　　　　
    };　　　　　　
    setTimeout(tasks, 5000);
    // return promise object
    return dtd.promise(s);
  };
}

var s = "hhh";
$.when(t(s))
  .then(function() {
    alert(s);
  }).then(function() {
    alert(s);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I can only got "hhh" instead of "hhhhhh"...

2
How to invoke promise chain with different values?like a.then(b(c)).then(f(d))

I put all values in a object and then pass it on chain...

Comment: @Tushar Thanks,I'm going to edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alert in your `$.when` is alerting the global variable not the resolve in `tasks`

Also , you never call `wait()` and `tasks()` doesn't return anything.

The return of the promise only returns to `wait()` which never gets called. Returning to the inner function does not return to the outer function

Also you have no arguments in `then()` to receive the resolved data.
In order to get data to the second `then`, you need to return something from the first one

```js
var t = function (s) {
    var wait = function () {　　　　
        var dtd = $.Deferred();
        //new a Deferred object in function
        　　　　
        var tasks = function () {　　　　　　
            alert("complete!");
            s = s + "hhh";　　　　　　
            dtd.resolve(s); // change the state of deferred object　　　　　　
        };　　　　　　
        setTimeout(tasks, 2000);
        // return promise object
        return dtd.promise();
    };
   // return the promise inside `wait` 
   return wait()
}

var s = "hhh";
$.when(t(s)).then(function (resolvedData) {
    // return to the next then...just because we can
    return resolvedData; // must return something if want to access it in next then        
}).then(function(previousThenData) {       
    alert(previousThenData);// alert argument
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks,I solve it.But I note there is no "dtd" in "var wait = function ()",I want to know the difference..I imitate someone's case ...

Comment: because `dtd` is returned from the function. The one you have would over write it even if it was passed in

Comment: So ，It doesn't matter？

Comment: the deferred is created inside. If you wanted it created outside you could do that and pass it in. There really is no reason in example to even have `var wait`

Comment: I got some glimmering of it,Thanks again!